# Bootstrap Modal not showing on second element

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hey I am new to Bootstrap. I want to build a safe delete Button with Modals. When you click you will be ask: really want to delete? And then you can choose yes or no. There are more than one element in this field. At the first one it works fine. At the second element the same data are shown like in the first one. If you reload the page and click the second element only the backdrop is shown and no dialogue.

The code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteSecureDialoge" data-keyboard="true" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" id="close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Warning</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Are you sure to delete {{item._id}}?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="deleteItem(item)" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
            <button type="button" id="cancel" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In My other file its bind over

```
<div class="form-group">
            <span ng-include='"templates/buttons.jsp"'></span>
```

Any idear what cause this problem?

Comment: not sure it's the root cause of the problem, but it seems you are missing a closing `</div>`

Comment: in the full file there is a closing div element. i just cut out the important parts

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give a confirmation window while click on the delete button. Please fill it with your contents.

**HTML Part**

```
  <form >
    <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' type="submit" name="remove_levels" value="delete"><span class="fa fa-times"></span> Delete</button>
    </form>
    <div id="confirm" class="modal hide fade" style="background: blanchedalmond;">
      <div class="modal-body">
       <h1>  
        Are you sure to delete?
      </h1></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="delete">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn">No</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**JS PART**

```
$('button[name="remove_levels"]').on('click', function(e){
    var $form=$(this).closest('form');
    $('#confirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
});
```